# Почему при запуске вёрстки через index.html нет изображений, при этом при запуске через лайв-сервер картинки есть?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #333;
}

*,
*::before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 40px 0;

    border: 0;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

/* Container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Intro */
.intro {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    
    background: url("../images/intro.jpg") center no-repeat;
    -webkit-bacground-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.intro_inner {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 880px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.intro_tittle {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
}

.intro_tittle::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 60px auto;

    background-color: #fff;
}

.intro_suptittle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}


/* Header */
.header {
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header_inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header_logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Nav */
.nav {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav_link {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 550;
    transition: color .1s linear;

}

.nav_link::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
   

    background-color: #fce38a;
    opacity: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    transition: opacity .1s linear;
}

.nav_link:hover {
    color: #fce38a
}

.nav_link:hover::after, 
.nav_link.active::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav_link.active {
    color: #fce38a
}

/* Button */
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 8px 25px;

    border: 3px solid #fff;

    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: background .2s linear, color .2s linear ;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
    
}

/* Slider */
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slider_inner {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider_item {
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 23%;
    position: relative;

    border-top: 3px solid #fff;
    opacity: .7;

    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider_item.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider_item.active::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #f38181;

    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slider_num {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}


/* Section */

.section {
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.section--devices {
    padding-bottom: 0;

    background: url("/images/devices/fon.jpg") center no-repeat; 
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.section_header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.section_subtitle {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive; 
    font-weight: 400;
}

.section_title {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section_title::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #f38181;
}

.section_text {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #999;
}


/* About */

.about {
    margin-top: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about_item {
    width: 380px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #95e1d3;

}

.about_item:hover .about_img {
    transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
    transition: transform .2s linear;
}


.about_item:hover .about_img img {
    opacity: .1;
}

.about_item:hover .about_text {
    opacity: 1;

}

.about_img {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f38181, #fce38a);
    transition: transform .2s linear;
}

.about_img img {
    display: block;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
}

.about_text {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
}

/* Statistics */

.statistics {
    background-color: #95e1d3;
}

.stat {
    display: flex;
}

.stat_item {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #b5eae0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 70px 25px;
}

.stat_item:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #b5eae0;
}

.stat_count {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.stat_text {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}


/* Services */

.services {
    display: flex;
}

.services_item {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    padding-left: 85px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

.serv_icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 28px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.services_title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
}

.services_text {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #999;
}

/* Devices */

.devices {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.devices_item {
    display: block;
}

.devices_item--iphone {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -80px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
    <section class="section section--devices">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="section_header">
                <h3 class="section_subtitle">For all devices</h3>
                <h2 class="section_title">Unique design</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="devices">
                <img class="devices_item" src="/images/devices/ipad.png" alt="">
                <img class="devices_item devices_item--iphone" src="/images/devices/iphone.png" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: Вёрстка через лайв-сервер]

[image: Вёрстка через index.html]

Comment: Убери слеш `/`, и всё заработает как надо. Подробнее https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: Спасибо за хелпу :)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Обращайся)